# Node JS server written with Coffeescript works, but JS version does not

Tags: web-services, node.js, coffeescript, haproxy

I have two node servers as my backend servers with a haproxy server on the front to round robin incoming HTTP requests.  The server with coffee works fine, but the server with the compiled coffeescript version written in JS blows up after several hours of being up.  The coffee code and the compiled JS code look identical.  When the JS version blows up it starts send 502 responses.  These servers handle about 5 million requests/day(combined).  Anyone seen this problem?

Comment: Are you using a framework on top of Node's http, such as Express? Which version(s) of Node are running on the servers?

Comment: whats the error?  is it always the same?  more info...

Comment: I am using express 2.5 on both, and node 0.6.19 on both.  I have different routes to handle the incoming requests and in the coffee all the routes go to index.coffee.  One difference in the JS is that I split out each route into its own JS file for the response callback.  I don't see why that would make a difference b/c I just require the separate route file in my app.js.

Comment: Maybe you could try packaging all the JS into one file and see if that changes anything?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't your problem, but I had the exact issue when using chained methods a certain way.

```
obj.method1 "param1"
.method2 "param2"
.exec (err, res) ->
   ...
```

vs

```
obj.method1("param1")
.method2("param2")
.exec (err, res) ->
   ...
```

I was using method #1 without issue until I compiled to JS, at which point it failed. I don't know the node/coffee versions but this answer may help someone.